# (iOS/iPhone/XCode) UIWebView will not open google maps in integrated Maps application

Tags: iphone, xcode, google-maps, uiwebview, maps

My application I'm developing requires a user to be able to get directions to a specific location. I have a view set up to call a specific web page from my server with a form where they enter their address and it provides a link to Google Maps.

When submitting this page though Safari - it works great! User enters their address, clicks 'Go' and they are brought to the Maps application and guided to the destination. When using an instance of UIWebView within my application, the window loads Google Mobile Maps.

So far I have tried to edit the browser agent identifier and use Method Swizzling (neither worked). An instance of MapView within my application is not suitable because of the UI, otherwise I would have used that approach.

**Basically, I want the google maps link within my UIWebView to open in the Maps application as it would in Safari.**

Ideas?

---

User presses the button hbgView to bring up hbgViewController using this code:

```
-(IBAction)hbgButton:(id)sender{
    hbgViewController *hbgView=[[hbgViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:hbgView animated:YES];
}
```

Then, I load the UIWebView session with the form using this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [svcWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"...com/mobile/map/hbg.html"]]];
}
```

The form code of the hbg.html document is as follows:

```
<script>
function redirect()
{
var baseUrl = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="
var suffix = "&daddr=endaddress&hl=en";
document.gmform.action=baseUrl+document.getElementById('url').value+suffix;
}
</script>
<form name="gmform" method="post" onsubmit="redirect()">
<input type="text" id="url">
<input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

Comment: Post some code so that can be more understandable to what exactly you want to do.

Comment: Do you use the form only in your app?

Comment: Yup - only in this app. The page is designed only for use in this app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-(IBAction)hbgdirButton:(id)sender{
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?q=harrisburg+pa&hl=en"]];
}
```

`http://maps.google.com/maps?q=` must be the prefix of the link

Comment: Does this work in a webview though, as per your original question?

Answer (score 0):

To persuade your app to open a link in the maps app, you will need to use the openURL method a bit like this;

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://maps.google.com?saddr=xxx&daddr=yyy&hl=en"]]
```

I do this in one of my apps and it works a treat. Obviously you've now handed off to the maps app and can't navigate back to your own though, so this only works for very specific use cases.

Comment: The only thing that concerns me about this is that I need to load the initial UIWebView for the user to submit the address information from the page listed on my server, this will load this upon page load and take it out of my application.

Comment: I don't think you have a choice if you want to offer directions though. Google Maps terms and conditions are quite strict in this regard. You could look to a third party - cloudmade do open source maps for iphone that you can embed in your app and I see they now do directions as well - so that might be the way to go.

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm looking to have the directions embedded into the application - I want this link to open the Maps application.